# Integrating a widget in nuxtjs

Tags: file, vue.js, widget

since I'm a complete beginner to Nuxtjs and vuejs, I'm still learning the basics. My problem is: How do I integrate a weather widget (generated from a website's service) into my nuxtjs page?

This is the widget's generated link: https://darksky.net/widget/default/54.3333,9.7101/uk12/de.js?width=100%&height=350&title=Borgstedt&textColor=333333&bgColor=FFFFFF&transparency=false&skyColor=undefined&fontFamily=Default&customFont=&units=uk&htColor=333333&ltColor=C7C7C7&displaySum=yes&displayHeader=yes'

I just pastet this with a  tag in my  section in my vue file. This doesn't work. I can imagine that I have to put this into the  section beneath the  section. But, in which form and how do I display this then? (Code to be written into the  section)

Thanks in advance for your help from an absolute newbie ;)

This is a screenshot of my code as it is right now:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VnB5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a component in `components` called `WeatherWidget.vue`

```
<template>
    <iframe :src="src"></iframe>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['src']
  }
</script>
```

Include that in your page

```
import WeatherWidget from '~/components/WeatherWidget.vue'
```

Use that component

```
components: { WeatherWidget }
```

Define the SRC for the weatherwidget in your data of your page:

```
data () {
  return {
    weatherWidgetSrc: 'https://darksky.net/widget/default/54.3333,9.7101/uk12/de?domain="+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+"&auth=1570731804_822dd4162ab203ebfdfb6574abec68d9&width=100%25&amp;height=350&amp;title=Borgstedt&amp;textColor=333333&amp;bgColor=FFFFFF&amp;transparency=false&amp;skyColor=undefined&amp;fontFamily=Default&amp;customFont=&amp;units=uk&amp;htColor=333333&amp;ltColor=C7C7C7&amp;displaySum=yes&amp;displayHeader=yes'
  }
}
```

And pass that as a property to the weatherwidget in your page:

```
<weather-widget :src="weatherWidgetSrc"></weather-widget>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, you're awesome!